# "These terms only appear in links pointing to this page"

Tags: google-search

Sometimes when searching for something in Google, after clicking a result's cache, some keywords are said to "only appear in links pointing to this page". I was wondering how to find out these "links"?

For example, I searched "recognizer, parser, automaton" in Google, and clicked on the following cache of a hit: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:cTSqyh405EkJ:en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata_theory+recognizer,+parser,+automaton&CD=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=Ubuntu&source=www.Google.com

It says

> These search terms are highlighted: automaton These terms only appear
>   in links pointing to this page: recognizer parser

Answer (score 1):

You can find all pages that link to your site by searching for:

```
link:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata_theory
```

However it is not possible to search *within* that pages and it does not show all back links but that's as close as you can get with Google. [Yahoo Site Explorer](http://siteexplorer.search.yahoo.com/) gives you more backlinks but does not let you search them either.